# Difference between Memoization Implementations - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, memoization

What is the difference (if any exists) between these memoization implementations?  Is there a use case where one is preferable to the other?  (I included this `Fibo` recursion as an example)

Put another way: is there a difference between checking `if some_value in self.memo:` and `if some_value not in self.memo:`, and if so, is there a case where one presents a better implementation (better optimized for performance, etc.)?

```
class Fibo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.memo = {}

    """Implementation 1""" 
    def fib1(self, n):
        if n in [0,1]:
            return n

        if n in self.memo:
            return self.memo[n]

        result = self.fib1(n - 1) + self.fib1(n - 2)

        self.memo[n] = result

        return result

    """Implementation 2"""
    def fib2(self, n):
        if n in [0,1]:
            return n

        if n not in self.memo:
            result = self.fib2(n - 1) + self.fib2(n - 2)

            self.memo[n] = result

        return self.memo[n]

# Fibo().fib1(8) returns 21
# Fibo().fib2(8) returns 21
```

Comment: `in` and `not in` should require approximately the same time complexity - the retrieval is `O(1)` where the time involved is in hashing the key value, then looking up the hash in the underlying hash table.  You could always try `timeit` to find out for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no significant performance difference in these implementations.  In my opinion `fib2` is a more readable/pythonic implementation, and should be preferred.

One other recommendation I would make, is to initialise the memo in `__init__` like this:

```
self.memo = {0:0, 1:1}
```

This avoids the need to make a conditional check inside each and every call, you can simply remove the first two lines of the `fib` method now.